# Formatting RIGHT cells based on specific cell's value

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I want to format RIGHT cells based on specific cells' value in a row

For example, in the picture, in row 1 I set: A1 = A, D1 = B and G1 = C then right cells of them will be formatted in different format.

In this same row, when we change position of A, B, C to another cell the format will be change accordingly.

I could not do on my own, sadly...:)!
Sample formating:
[image: Sample formating]

Comment: You must click `Merge & Center` and then click `Align Right`. Your question is confusing sorry I don't get it.

Comment: Never use `Merge & Center`  - it's the destroyer of cell selection.

Comment: Thank you! But I am asking about conditional formating :D!

Answer (score 0):

Select A1 to C1 and create three conditional formatting rules that use a formula. Use these three formulas in the three rules:

[image]

Create similar rules for the cells D1 to F1, where the rule references $D$1, and another set of rules for the cells G1 to K1 where the rules reference $G$1.

If you want to apply the rules to the following rows, don't use a $ sign in front of the row number, so the row numbers is kept as a relative reference and the rule is applied to the cells in the same row.

Comment: Thank you! But my question is how to automatically format based on cell value. For example, in same row 1, I change value at C1 = B > RIGHT cells will change format accordingly.

Comment: Yes. That's what my suggestion does. You set up conditional formatting rules once, and after that the cell format will change automatically when the value changes. If this is not what you want, please edit your question and give some more examples of what you want to see. Then post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution from my colleague: =LOOKUP(REPT("Z",255),$A1:A1)="ANYTHING"